# Is in my computer sensor which checks DDR1 Ram temp?

Tags: memory, temperature

Is there any sensor which checks temp of ram?

Answer (score 3):

you can test this by using a tool like [everest ultimate edition](http://www.lavalys.com/support/downloads). Even though you don´t have other than a evaluation license, it will show you which sensors are in your machine. Maybe you won´t be able to see theyr temperature in the test version but at least, you will know which sensors you´ve got.

Comment: Unfortunately, Everest can't show their location on a motherboard :(. Still, +1 for mentioning it.

Comment: I can see if its the South or Northbridge sensor, that´s why i guessed it should display ram or something also by name, but I will keep looking for another solution. I personally think the temperature in a computer is something important ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is. Sensors on the motherboard most will most likely display temperature of north bridge or of some arbitrary point on the motherboard. If you didn't actually place sensor on RAM, there probably isn't any.

Another problem is that the way RAM chips heat makes temperature measurements difficult. It can happen that on a module only one or two chips are hot and the rest are cold or it could happen that all chips are hot. This makes measurements difficult because location of the sensor itself can make considerable impact on readings.